# Export datetime to Excel: One day different issue only for 1900-Jan and 1900-Feb

Tags: .net, excel, datetime

I'm using Epplus & ClosedXml to export data to Excel. When I tried to export value in the range between 1900-1-1 and 1900-2-28, the exported value in Excel always greater than 1 day.

Ex: When export 1900-1-1, the value in excel is 1900-1-2, and 1900-2-28 will be converted to 1900-2-29

I guess the issue that Excel supports the date 1900-2-29 but .Net is not. Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year. Excel thinks 1900 is a leap year: it isn’t, but this is probably embedded in so much code globally that it can’t be changed ...

Comment: Also covered in [Dates And Times In Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm). And a nice read around this Excel-leap-year-bug: [My First BillG Review](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/) by Joel Spolsky.